# How to move login from SQL Server 2008R2 to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a SQL Server 2008R2 database that I have limited access to and where the SA account password has been lost. I need to be able to copy the logins from that database to a SQL Server 2014 database.

I'd create/run `sp_help_revlogin` except that the one login account I do have doesn't have any rights in the master database. Years ago I had a script that just overrode the SID assigned to the objects in the secondary database, but that doesn't appear to be supported since 2004 (I haven't been around SQL Server in a long while).

I tried looking at the new SSIS/SMO tools and they appear to require named pipes as the protocol, but I'm limited on what protocols I can use due to customer security restrictions. I tried looking to see if I could use TCP/IP Sockets instead of named pipes, but everything has changed so much that I'm not sure where to even look.

So I have some questions:

1. Is it possible to use TCP/IP Sockets when using SSIS?
2. Is there a better way to try to move logins across servers than `sp_help_revlogin`?
3. Assuming that there aren't any applications using the SA account on the old server, what are my risks in resetting the SA account password so that I can go in and create the `sp_help_revlogin` procedure?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1. Definitely. Do you get some kind of TCP/IP error when you run a particular step? Please post it. 2. Not sure  3. Not sure. Can I suggest in future you use windows authetication, not SQL authentication (i.e. sa)

Comment: Nick.  It just times out.  It I try net use \\host\IPC$ to test for named pipes, I get "System Error 53".  When I use SMO "Test Connection" I receive "Failed to Connect to Server".  I'm able to connect to server using Remote Desktop though so there's some network connectivity.

Comment: Can you connect to the server in SSMS using TCP/IP? is that when it times out? Can you follow the usual TCP/IP tests: 1. PIng the server. 2. Work what port the server is running on an use TELNET to test

Comment: Can't ping.  ICMP is blocked and Telnet may be as well.  I tried TELNET over 445 and 1433 with no success.  When I tried adding a database connection in SSIS, I received a message stating "Server was not found or was not accessible...provider (Named Pipes Provider, Error 40 Could not open connection to SQL Server.)  I did manage to go and verify what protocols were enabled on the SQL server and have Shared Memory, TCP and Named Pipes enabled.

Comment: If you want to use TCP/IP, make sure the client is set up to use it. Also confirm that the SQL Server is indeed port 1433, and confirm that the firewall is open.

Comment: Nick, the final solution was that IT hadn't opened up the firewall ports.  Once they did that, everything worked.  Thank you.

Comment: Great. `TELNET` is the one that confirms this, but you need to be certain the SQL Server is running on that port